# Can I use the .SHELLFLAGS variable to choose "bashrc" file in GNU-Make?

Tags: gnu-make

Is it possible to tell the `SHELL`, e.g. bash, to use a specific (bash)rc file using `.SHELLFLAGS`?

Below you will see two examples. The first shows what I want to do, and the second illustrates one way of achieving the desired result.

*The reason for me asking is that I have a `bashrc` file (from OpenFOAM) defining a bunch of variables and functions that I want to use in various recipes.*

Thank you for your time.

---

example (**not working**)

- file: `bashrc`:

  ```
  export HELLOWORLD="Hello World"
  ```
- file: `Makefile`:

  ```
  SHELL=/bin/bash
  .SHELLFLAGS=--rcfile bashrc --

  test:
      @\
      echo "$${HELLOWORLD}"
  ```

example (**working**)

- file: `bashrc`:

  ```
  export HELLOWORLD="Hello World"
  ```
- file: `Makefile`:

  ```
  .ONESHELL:
  SHELL=/bin/bash

  test: ; source bashrc
      @\
      echo "$${HELLOWORLD}"
  ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you read the bash man page related to the `--rcfile` option you'll find:

```
   --rcfile file
          Execute  commands  from file instead of the system wide initial‐
          ization file /etc/bash.bashrc and the standard personal initial‐
          ization  file ~/.bashrc if the shell is interactive (see INVOCA‐
          TION below).
```

Note particularly that the shell must be interactive for this to have any effect, but a shell that make invokes is of course not interactive.

Second, if you read the GNU make manual on `.SHELLFLAGS` you'll see that the default value is `-c` (or `-ec` in POSIX mode); the `-c` option allows the shell to read the script to run from the command line, which is how `make` invokes the shell.  This means when you replace `.SHELLFLAGS` with your own value, you have to include that.

So with your makefile when `make` runs the shell it will use this command line:

```
/bin/bash --rcfile bashrc -- 'echo "${HELLOWORLD}"'
```

which is clearly not going to work.  You need to set `.SHELLFLAGS` like this:

```
.SHELLFLAGS = --rcfile bashrc -ic --
```

The `-i` option forces an interactive shell, and you need the `-c` option to tell make to run the first non-option argument as a command.

Comment: I've tried this solution for a similar problem, and found that it ends up spawning multiple bash shell processes and make processes, which don't seem to die, every time you run `make`. Is there a way to avoid this?